# Golang FileServer with custom css

Tags: go

I've thought about creating a mini file server for my home with Go. Normally `http.FileServer` servers files and dirs ugly like this:

[image]

Is it possible to add CSS to this site? For example change colors. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Not directly, but it would be relatively trivial to write your own implementation that listed directories however you see fit. You can see the implementation in the standard library and use it as a basis for your own: https://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go?s=20189:20229#L695

Comment: Yes, with a link <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css" />  :: check here: Very basic golang http server
https://gist.github.com/iamphill/9dfafc668a3c1cd79bcd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hacky solution, making use of the fact that you can keep writing to a `http.ResponseWriter` after `http.FileServer` has done its work. Not recommended in general, but in this situation it might be acceptable.

```
package main

import (
        "io"
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

const (
        link = `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/style.css">`
)

func main() {
        fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp"))
        var handler http.HandlerFunc
        handler = func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                var (
                        url   = r.URL.Path
                        isDir = url[len(url)-1] == '/'
                )
                fs.ServeHTTP(w, r)
                if isDir {
                        io.WriteString(w, link)
                }
        }
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler))
}
```

Comment: There must be something else... why would the go authors return the directory as a PRE with a content-type in the header?